# In Amazon DynamoDB creating a version of the table items

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I have a item such as: 
"Item": {
    "model": 32590038899,
    "date": 10-09-2015,
    "price":100
  }

"hash_key_attribute_name": "model"

"range_key_attribute_name": "date"

My problem is that new items gets inserted a lot so there is chance that items with same model number may come and they may not be same product.This may due to regions where the product is available.So i need a setup where i need to keep a copy of the product, if such a case arises and in future after inspection or requirement i can bring back the item. I am looking for a kind of version system. Currently the product gets deleted due to same primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Put simply: if your primary key isn't unique, then you aren't using the correct field as your primary key.

> ...there is chance that items with same model number may come and they
>   may not be same product.This may due to regions where the product is
>   available...

It sounds like your primary key needs to be a composite of region and product ID. Or perhaps you need a separate table for each region.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a unique id attribute to your item, a uuid works well, such as

```
{ id: "53f382ae-94b8-4910-b8f1-384f46dc10d8",
  model: 32590038899, 
  date: "10-09-2015", 
  price:100 
}
```

Change your table schema to have just a hash key attribute name - *id*.

Add a global secondary index with hash key - *model*, range key - *date*.

Global secondary indexes can contain items where the primary keys collide. With this schema you will prevent items from being overwritten and you can query for items with a given model number.